# Where does libGL end, and libGLU begin?

Tags: opengl

The function 'glCreateShader' is not available until I include libGLU as a library, next to libGL.

'glCreateShader' is a core OpenGL functionality.

Does this mean that libGLU should always be linked to any application that uses libGL? Why are they split apart in the first place?

Thank you.

Comment: libGLU is expected to export functions starting with `glu` prefix (and `glCreateShader` is not one of them). These functions rely on legacy OpenGL API, hence there is no reason to use this library in modern applications.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/opengl/glu-functions

Comment: Referred linkage behavior should be induced by some other aspects, not by necessity yo use `libGLU`. Probably you should mention more details about your system and `libGL` library used for development / running application (on Linux platform proprietary OpenGL drivers may spoil environment).

Comment: glCreateShader is on all systems I know defined in libgl. If you encounter something else, then please show the code that you compile and the exact compile command that you issue.

Comment: `nm -D libGL.so | grep glCreateShader` shows the sysmbol on my Linux system.  Whereas `nm -D libGLU.so | grep glCreateShader` yields nothing. Remember the link specification order is important. Show how you are linking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

[Load OpenGL Functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions)

> Loading OpenGL Functions is an important task for initializing OpenGL after creating an OpenGL context. You are strongly advised to use an OpenGL Loading Library instead of a manual process.

[OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)

> An OpenGL Loading Library is a library that loads pointers to OpenGL functions at runtime, core as well as extensions. This is required to access functions from OpenGL versions above 1.1 on most platforms.

In your `gl.h` you will find two sections, one for the function type definitions and one guarded by the macro `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES`, which contains the function declarations. If on your platform `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` is defined, then the function symbols are exported and you don't need to load the functions manually, but since it is recommended to load the functions and on most systems `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` is not definded, it is basically 'mandatory' to load the functions manually, which means core functions will not be available.

I don't know what kind of error you get (compile or link error) but always check first if the function is at your disposal and who (compiler/linker) raises the error (function not found vs. undefined reference).

---

> Why are they split apart in the first place?

Because [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) is one thing and [OpenGL Utility Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library) (GLU) is something else. In 'ancient' times GLU provided some useful functions (utilities, hence the name) but since then time brought change and with the 'modern' era of OpenGL, GLU became obsolete (you can still use it with legacy OpenGL though).